# Ag-grid with AngularJS - header width is not aligning with data columns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ag-grid

[Update] I will add an additional 200 points (total 300) if anyone gets [my snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mawg/9ex225ye/4/) working, with headers and data columns aligned.

---

This is my first attempt with [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/). I assign the grid header like this:

```
var stationAnalyticsColumnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Station #", field: "station_id",   width: 150, sort: 'asc'},
    {headerName: "Station name",   field: "station_name", width: 150, sort: 'desc'},
    {headerName: "Total visitors",   field: "total_visit_count", width: 150, sort: 'desc'},
    {headerName: "Busiest day (visitors)",   valueGetter: BusiestDayValueGetter, width: 150, comparator: BusiestDayComparator},
];
```

I am fetching the data by AJAX, so when my `$http.get` returns success, accoding to the docs, I should be able to

```
$scope.stationAnalyticsGridOptions.api.refreshView();
```

or

```
$scope.stationAnalyticsGridOptions.api.refreshRows(data);
```

but neither of those seems to work (no data is shown), so I use

```
$scope.stationAnalyticsGridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
```

and the data shows just fine.

My problem is that the headers don't align with the data. How do I do that? I also want the grid columns to resize as I drag the headers to resize them.

[image]

---

[Update]  Still working on the Plunk. Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

#### View

```
<div ag-grid="stationAnalyticsGridOptions" 
     class="ag-fresh ag-basic" 
     style="height:400px; width:80%">
```

#### Controller

```
var stationAnalyticsColumnDefs = [
   {headerName: "Station #", field: "station_id",   width: 150, sort: 'asc'},
   {headerName: "Station name",   field: "station_name", width: 150, sort: 'desc'},
   {headerName: "Total visitors",   field: "total_visit_count", width: 150, sort: 'desc'},
   {headerName: "Busiest day (visitors)",   valueGetter: BusiestDayValueGetter, width: 150, comparator: BusiestDayComparator},
];

$scope.stationAnalyticsGridOptions = {
    columnDefs: stationAnalyticsColumnDefs,
    rowData: $scope.eventStationsAnalyticData,
    enableColResize: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
};
```

---

[Update] I tried to create a working Fiddle, to reproduce the question, but failed; the table does not even display. You can find the Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/mawg/9ex225ye/4/

Can anyone get it working - with the header width and data column width aligning?

Please fork my Fiddle, rather than starting from scratch, and retain the variable names, etc

Comment: Could you add the `data` object you parse into `setRowData()`? I guess the alignment breaks after you set row data?

Comment: I will add  this as soon as I get home form work in 10 hours or so. I suspect that you are correct, and that it the call of `setRowData()` which cause sthre problem (although I can't imagine why)

Comment: I've create a testing scenario in my machine and it does work fine over here. Could you please add your full `gridOptions` too?

Comment: I certianly will. Btw, do `refreshView()` or `refreshRows()` work for you? Thos would seem to be preferable to `setRowData()`. Plese let me know if you have a Fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mono49s7/1/

Comment: An excellent and comprehensive Fiddle. I particularly like that you also use `setRowData()`, as I do. I will post my code this evening & imagine that we will soon spot the error

Comment: A simple fiddle to reproduce your problem would be glad.

Comment: Still working fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/sb9j25gc/ have you tried to add `angularCompileHeaders: true` ?

Comment: I will take your Plunk and modify it for my code. I will let you know how it goes, but, for now, you have earned the answer (and the bonus). Thanks !  Please post an answer which points to your Plunk, so that I Can accept it.

Comment: Glad to help, but does it fix your problem in the end?

Comment: Still working on it :-(   Can you see anything from the updated question?

Comment: No, it does also work with your inline CSS https://jsfiddle.net/9ex225ye/1/ A plnkr to reproduce your problem would be still nice to have.

Comment: have you been able to create your plnkr right now? :) I will stay in the chat now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137528/discussion-between-lin-and-mawg).

Comment: My company firewall blocks chat :-( I have a 5 hour daily commute, so barely one hour at home before bed.  I will try to reply tonight (with Plunk), but it might be Saturday before I really have time for code. Sorry :-(

Comment: Don't worry, ill be here. Don't let the bounty on this question flew away.

Comment: I was trying, but can't make my fiddle work yet, like it does on my `localhost`. I need to get to bed for 5:30am alarm tomorrow, and will try again tomorrow night   https://jsfiddle.net/mawg/9ex225ye/4/

Comment: I still can't get this fiddle to work - any ideas?

Comment: Please join me in chat.

Comment: I am sorry; I missed that

Comment: Lets fix it today

Comment: Yes, please - can you make it work?

Comment: Please join me in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137528/discussion-between-lin-and-mawg

Comment: Thx! I still want to solve your problem. Join me in chat if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setup your `gridOptions` including `angularComileHeader: true` to ensure your headers does work with `AngularJS` in the right way. Please check this [runnable plnkr](https://jsfiddle.net/sb9j25gc/) and compare it with your solution. Also ensure you using the latest version of `ag-grid`.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: $scope.rowData,
  angularCompileHeaders: true,
  enableColResize: true,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableFilter: true
};
```

Comment: An excellent and comprehensive Fiddle.  This is a model answer. I wish that more of them were like this :-)