# Width of custom headers in ag-grid (angular) doesn't match with column's width

Tags: angular, angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a custom component that implements both `ICellRendererAngularComp`, `IHeaderAngularComp`. It is to be used both as a cell and header. However, when the component is rendered as a header, It doesn't span across full width.
[image: The width of the custom component is set to 100% in it's css.]

```
colDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "Text",
      headerName: "Text",
      headerComponent: GridCellComponent,
      headerComponentParams: {
         .....
      },
      cellRenderer: GridCellComponent,
    },
]
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42657490/17143536), But the solution mentioned doesn't seem to work now. Please ask if you need any specifics related to problem.